what is the correct way to write byte array into unmanaged memory?
I faced a problem when I tried to write into virtual memory in C# program, I allocated the memory using VirtuAlloc function, and then write 10 bytes array into the memory using Marshal.Copy function, but when I tried to read  10 bytes from the same address, it gives me other bytes.
I tried this code to write array into allocated memory, but when I try to read the bytes from the address I wrote byte to, it gives me other bytes, take a look at the code:
byte[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

Console.WriteLine("arr: ");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++){ 
    Console.Write("0x{0:X2} , ", arr[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine("");

UInt32  codeAddr = VirtualAlloc(0, (UInt32)arr.Length, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
Console.WriteLine("Code Address: 0x{0:X8}",codeAddr);

Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, (IntPtr) (codeAddr), arr.Length);

Console.WriteLine("arr at 0x{0:X8}: ",codeAddr);  
byte value=0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++){
    value = Marshal.ReadByte(codeAddr, i);
    Console.Write("0x{0:X2} , ", value);
}
Console.WriteLine("");
  

the output is

C:\Users\thm\Desktop>koko.exe 
arr:
0x01 , 0x02 , 0x03 , 0x04 , 0x05 , 0x06 , 0x07 , 0x08 , 0x09 , 0x0A ,
Code Address: 0x00770000
arr at 0x00770000:
0x00 , 0x00 , 0x77 , 0x00 , 0x0A , 0xD5 , 0x0A , 0x00 , 0xB7 , 0x46 ,             

but I think it must print 0x01 ..... 0xA twice, why it did not read the written bytes in that address

@JoséRamírez It does need to be pinned, but you don't need to take the address of the array.

@MatthewWatson, hello.  Thanks for the clarification.  I kinda suspected it:  It would not have compiled because of data types, so that should have hinted me that my thinking was going the wrong way.

I reproduced the error and I think it's due to how you have defined the extern VirtualAlloc - to return UInt32 and not the system native pointer size IntPtr.
UInt32 codeAddr = VirtualAlloc(0, (UInt32)arr.Length, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

if you change it to return IntPtr, it will work.
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(int lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);


You should also pin the array to prevent it being moved by the GC while Marshal.Copy() is being called (unlikely, but possible and would cause really hard to diagnose errors). e.g.: var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(array); Marshal.Copy(array, 0, address, array.Length); handle.Free();

it works perfectly

I would just use Marshal.AllocHGlobal to allocate the memory. At least unless you need the extra control VirtualAlloc gives you.
try{
  var codeAddr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(arr.Length);
  ...
}
finally{
  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(codeAddr );
}

